# remove double single quotes but not single quote

Tags: regex, ruby

How to remove double single quotes but not the single quote in a string in Ruby? For instance from `That's 'large'`, to `That's large`.

Comment: What about "'Twas Bess' cat that was making all the ruckus."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\B'((?:(?!'\B)[\s\S])*)'
```

Replace each match with `\1`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NiiskN/5)**

Code(**[Result](https://rextester.com/OKRL98554)**):

```
re = /\B'((?:(?!'\B)[\s\S])*)'/m
str = 'That\'s \'large\'
The 69\'ers\' drummer won\'t like this.
He said, \'it\'s clear this does not work\'. It does not fit the \'contractual obligations\''
subst = '\\1'

result = str.gsub(re, subst)

# Print the result of the substitution
puts result
```

**Explanation:**

- `\B` - matches a non-word boundary
- `((?:(?!'\B)[\s\S])*)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character `[\s\S]` which (does not start with `'` followed by a non-word boundary). This is captured in Group 1.
- `'` - matches a `'`

Comment: The 69'ers' drummer won't like this.

Comment: He said, 'it's clear this does not work'. It does not fit the 'contractual obligations'.

Comment: @Schwern I have [updated my answer](https://regex101.com/r/NiiskN/5) to cover your test cases too.

Comment: @Potato thanks for this. How to extend this to also remove non-word characters like `; : ! $ \n`?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those quagmires ike parsing XML or HTML that can't be done with a regex, but you can sorta pretend like it's mostly going to work. You can tweak it forever and not get right.

You could look for balanced quotes, that is only quotes in pairs, but this doesn't help. Is `That's 'large'` to be stripped as `Thats large'` or `That's large`?

Instead you need to give it an understanding of English grammar and when a `'` is an [apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) versus a quote. Something simple that knows the basics of contractions and possessives. Contractions: `don't`, `won't`, `I'll`. Possessives: `Joe's` and `s'`. And maybe you can knock up a regex to skip those.

But it rapidly gets complicated. `KO'd`. Or what if you wish to indicate a particular pronunciation: `fo'c's'le`. Or someone's name `O'Doole`.

What you *might* be able to get away with stripping a pair of quotes that start at the beginning of a word and the end of a word. `It's clear he said, 'this isn't a contraction'.` Matching the quote in front of `this` and the quote at the end of `contraction` is probably maybe safe.

```
# Use negative look behind and ahead to look for quotes which are
# not after and before a word character.
# Use a non-greedy match to catch multiple pairs of quotes.
re = /(?<!\w)'(.*?)'(?!\w)/
sentence.gsub(re, '\1')
```

This works in a lot of cases.

```
That's 'large' -> That's large
Eat at Joe's -> Eat at Joe's
I'll be Jane's -> I'll be Jane's
Jones' three cats' toys. -> Jones' three cats' toys.
It's clear he said, 'this isn't a contraction'. -> It's clear he said, this isn't a contraction.
'scare quotes' -> scare quotes
The 69'ers' drummer -> The 69'ers' drummer
Was She's success greater, or King Solomon's Mines's? -> Was She's success greater, or King Solomon's Mines's?
The 69'er's drummer and their 'contractual obligations'. -> The 69'er's drummer and their contractual obligations.
He said, 'it's clear this doesn't work'. -> He said, it's clear this doesn't work.
```

But not always.

```
His 'n' Hers's first track is called 'Joyriders'. -> His n Hers's first track is called Joyriders.
```

Like I said, this is one of those problems that looks simple but is extremely complicated and you can never get quite right. It can suck down a lot of time. I'd recommend ditching the requirement if possible.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but have to ask to how to extend your answer so that it can also remove any non-word characters?

Comment: @stt106 Can you give some examples?

Comment: In addition to removing double single quote while keeping the apostrophe, I also want to remove non-word characters like comma, semicolon, special signs like `$%`

Comment: @stt106 `Would you pay me $100 for that answer?` Is that supposed to be `Would you pay me 100 for that answer`? Or should it understand the `$100` and `?` are valid punctuation? Ask a new question, provide clear before and after examples like I have, and link it in a comment here so I can have a look.

Comment: Updated the question with a renewed example. I think I just need your current answer AND `[\W]` but not sure how to combine them. Thanks.

Comment: @stt106 Please don't change the question after it's been answered, it invalidates the answers, and the edited question won't get much attention. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation — if the single quotes only occur around word characters, that is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or the _ (underscore) character. you can use this:

```
phrase = "That's 'large' and not 'small', but it's still 'amazing'."
phrase.gsub(/'(\w*)'/, '\1')
=> "That's large and not small, but it's still amazing."
```

But as Schwern says, if you're trying to do anything other than a bit of simple text manipulation, you'll soon find yourself bogged down by edge cases.

Comment: Yeah, right. Regex isn't suitable for anything other than simple text manipulation. Too many edge cases, as you have skillfully pointed out. Would be nice to hear more about what the OP is wanting to do.